# How to remove a textbox from html table using jquery or javascript without losing the textbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a column which contains textboxes, I need to remove the textboxes using jQuery/JavaScript while keeping the textbox values.

Things I've tried so far :

```
// removes the entire textboxes and the values inside it 
mytable.find('input:text').remove();

//doesnt seem to work
$('#mytable').find('input:text').contents().unwrap();
```

I know it has to do with parent/children node.

Comment: `.style("display","none");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace element with its own text, then you can use:

```
$('#mytable').find('input:text').replaceWith(function(){
    return this.value;
});
```

> I know it has to do with parent/children node

`input` element is void element, it hasn't any content.

Comment: or `return document.createTextNode( this.value );` to ensure plain text; otherwise, if the input elements contain `<`, etc. the result will be interpreted as HTML

Comment: @PaulRoub Good point but it really depends what is expected behaviour

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for taking the time to answer.. all of them were helpful.. but this was the easiest solution in my scenario.. appreciate it :D

Answer (score 5):

You can just set the CSS of the element using jquery`.css()`. Try as below

```
$('#mytable').find('input:text').css("display","none");
```

or

```
 $('#mytable').find('input:text').css("visibility","hidden");
```

As @Rayon mentioned, the element can be made hidden using `hide()` of jQuery.

```
 $('#mytable').find('input:text').hide();
```

Comment: @Lal. How about `hide()` :P ?

Comment: See my edited answer @RayonDabre .. Thanks for your valuable suggestion..:)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @DrCord...

Comment: NP, glad to help :D. I realized that I thought `.style()` was right at first too, but that's mixing pure JS with jQuery :D

Comment: Yeah..I know...just got mixed up...:D.. Anyway, thanks for the edit once more..:)

Comment: I don't understand expected behaviour like this. Regarding op attempt, looks like he still wants to display input text

Comment: "I need to remove the textboxes using jQuery/JavaScript while keeping the textbox values."..is what the OP said..I suppose, he is trying to hide the element, but he needs the element's value.. @A.Wolff

Comment: @Lal ya it could mean that but why would he would like to keep it like that? I mean if it was inside a form it would make sense but then anyway he would need to set name attribute in order to submit these inputs to server. So imho, that's an unclear question

Comment: yeah...@A.Wolff .. The question is incomplete..I just answered because I felt, this was what the OP needed.. He will have to reply..Lets wait..;)

Comment: thanks guys .. i guess i was a little vague in my question.. what i was trying to do was take the table and convert it to excel.. but the textboxes kept showing up in the excel file.. i needed to get rid of the textboxes while retaining the values inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery each function to find each input text type and get its value then remove it. It will remove text input and place its value in same

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var textValue = "";
        $("#myTable td").each(function(){

            if($(("input[type='text']"),$(this)).length > 0){
                textValue = $(("input[type='text']"),$(this)).val();
                $(("input[type='text']"),$(this)).remove();
                $(this).html(textValue);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <table id="myTable">

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="4" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```